# Windows 2008 startup script will not run?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, startup-scripts

I am trying to get a very simple batch script to run when my Windows 2008 Server (R2) system starts up.  I have added the script to the "Startup Scripts" in the local group policy by running `gpedit.msc`, and I see the script listed under `Windows Settings/Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)/Startup` when I run `rsop.msc`, but the script is not being executed.  The "Last Executed" column in `rsop` is empty even after a reboot, and a file that should be created by the script is never created.

At the moment, the entire contents of the script are:

```
rem Check if this script is running.
date /t > c:\temp\flag
```

The target directory (`c:\temp`) exists.  The script is called `c:\scripts\startup.bat`, and works fine if I run it by hand.

Comment: What NTFS permissions are assigned to the c:\temp and c:\scripts folder and to the batch file itself?

Comment: Are you going to chop the local group policy editor into little pieces and boil it in oil? ;)

Comment: It hasn't annoyed me anywhere near as much as the BSD automounter.  At this point I assume it's *my* problem...Windows administration really isn't my strength.

Comment: Rex: I'll update the question with ACLs in a moment; waiting for a service pack to apply...

Comment: You should grab a copy of psexec and run `psexec -s path\to\script.bat`. That will run it as System. That's a more accurate manual test than running it as the logged in user.

Comment: Argh.  `psexec` was giving me weird errors, and replacing the script (`rename oldname newname, type newname > oldname`) made them go way.  After applying SP1, I can't reproduce the problem.  MDMarra, if you post your comment re: `psexec` as an answer I'll accept that one, since it seemed to provide a useful diagnostic.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should grab a copy of psexec and run `psexec -s path\to\script.bat`. That will run it as System. That's a more accurate manual test than running it as the logged in user, since startup scripts run as SYSTEM.

Comment: I didn't know about `psexec`, so that was very helpful.  The permissions on the file were odd and when running with psexec I was getting a weird "command not found" sort of error.  Re-generating the script seemed to fix things, so I'm chalking it up to a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

check the registry key hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run

You can add your script there if it is not already

http://www.akadia.com/services/windows_registry.html

otherwise check permissions on the folder to make sure the system account has write access

Comment: You should really switch your two points around so that the answer to the actual question is on top and a suggestion for a workaround is second. I'd like to upvote you, since it sounds like an NTFS permission problem, but not if the workaround is the first suggestion.

Comment: I believe that items added to this key are run after someone logs in, not at system startup.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work for me (granted on Windows Server 2012), I had to do the following:

1. Run `gpedit.msc`, go to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts and double-click `Startup`
2. Click `Show Files` and **paste a Shortcut to my script** in the folder that pops up
3. Back in the the Startup Properties dialog, click `Add` then `Browse` and select your shortcut.
4. Click `OK` and reboot.

The pasting of the shortcut was the critical bit. Browsing to a location outside of the Scripts/Startup folder resulted in nothing working.